Syncfusion File Manager for NextJS with AWS S3 provider
I am trying to intergate the Syncfusion File manager S3 Provider in my NextJS application. But I don't find any clear view to connect my S3 with File manager.
I don't know where to put AWS credentials and what to put in the url, downloadURL, uploadURL. And also wonder how to use the Syncfusion S3 provider.
